# Paste option not available on Flutterflow

Tags: flutterflow

I am unable to paste any form of text in my Flutterflow app projects. I have to manually write the contents in the text field.

I have followed Flutterflow projects direction and enabled clipboard in the website bar in the lock icon but that hasn't resolved my issue.

How can I paste text from other sources into Flutterflow apps?

Thanks in advance.

I allowed clipboard in the website bar where the lockscreen was, but it has not resolved the issue.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5s5e.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste text directly using the shortcut keys on Mac and windows. If you are unable to paste, please check permissions in your browsers or PC.